# How to automatically scroll when div expands at bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lately I have come into a dead end. I'm trying to expand the footer (#footernotes) and that works, it's basically a div behind the body (done with z-index) and when you click on a button it moves down. The scroll bar goes with it too, meaning that the page is now longer.

But what I'm trying to do is to make the viewport move with the expanded div. What happens now is that when I press the button (.secret) the div (#footernotes) comes in but it is still out of the viewport UNLESS you manually scroll to view the longer page.

So to some it up, how do you make the viewport automatically scroll down after you expanded the page? In other words, how do you make the viewport stay at the bottom of the page.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.secret').click(function(){
            $("#footernotes").animate({top: "100px"}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div id="footer">
    <a href="" class="secret" ><div id="buttontest" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green;"></div></a>
    <div id="footernotes">
    </div>
</div> <!-- end #footer -->
```

And the CSS for #footernotes

```
#footernotes {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: -400;
}
```

**EDIT:** While typing up the question I figure out the answer, you have to use the scrollTop. I have added the line code in the example below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.secret').click(function(){
                $("#footernotes").animate({top: "100px"}, 1000);
                $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: "210px"},1000);
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

You can still answer this if you think there is a better way, I just thought I'll leave this question posted in case other people have the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('divID').scrollIntoView();
```

try and see if that would do the job.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @AaronBlenkush(?)

Comment: Also, if there is more content after the `div` you're scrolling to, you might want to give the method a `false` argument to align it with the bottom of the view rather than the top. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

Comment: @mavili I tried using that line of code it seems to just break the animation. It just refreshed the current page. Could I be implementing it wrong? I added it just under the 4th line of the html file.

Comment: @mavili: i.e., for not using jQuery (there is a [scrollintoview plugin](https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview)) for a function that is native.

Comment: it should not refresh the page (I would be very surprised if it does!). However, I will give it a try with your code and see what happens.

Comment: Put the line of code right at the start of the function call. I tried it and it works fine.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush oh right. Well yeah, I hate using plugins when there's ways of doing things in the native form. Well, except if I already am using a framework in my documents, then I'd use whichever has less code (i.e. native or the framework method)

Comment: Tested it again and it seems the hashtag messed it up, I removed that and now it works fine. Only some browser problems now, with chrome and safari it works when you click twice. Firefox is doing great though. Thanks!!

Comment: oh, right! Sorry, the hashtag shouldn't have been there with the `getElementById()` method. My mistake. Just corrected it. But if it works now, great!

Comment: what is funny is I wasn't actually using the hashtag when testing on my own computer ;)

Comment: in my comment above I said put it at the start of the function, that might not be right. Put it AFTER the two animate methods and see if it works fine with the other browsers. It should.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using Jquery method .focus(). just need to add

$(divname / .class / #id).focus();

and it would be done.