# Keep view on bottom of the page when textarea is expand dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use `textarea` as a comment box. Bellow the element I have a `button`. The user can write his text in the `textarea` and when the text hits the element's bottom, I use a small javascript function to expand the `textarea`'s height automatically.

#### Problem

The problem is that after the element hits the very bottom of the window, the button is disappeared, but the comment box expand correctly.

#### Question

How is it possible to keep the view of the post button (in my example the whole `comment-post-area` class) in the page without loosing it?

#### Code and Example provided bellow

```js
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
  o.rows = (o.value.split('\n').length);
}
```

```css
.comment-editor textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.comment-post-area .footer button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 2px solid RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-post-area">
  <form class="comment-post-form">
    <div class="comment-editor">
      <textarea placeholder="Leave a comment." onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this);" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <button type="submit">
        <span class="submit-text">Post</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4vrgqrpu/) `<!-- Same as above -->`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the related questions gave me the answer.

From [`@mavili`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418273/4108694)

> `document.getElementById('divID').scrollIntoView();`

So my code will become:

```js
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
  o.rows = (o.value.split('\n').length);
  
  // the bellow line was added to reflect my example
  document.getElementById('submit-section').scrollIntoView();
  // end of added code
}
```

```css
.comment-editor textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.comment-post-area .footer button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 2px solid RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-post-area">
  <form class="comment-post-form">
    <div class="comment-editor">
      <textarea placeholder="Leave a comment." onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this);" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" id="submit-section">
      <button type="submit">
        <span class="submit-text">Post</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

### Update

From [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) article:

> **This is an experimental technology**
>   Because this technology's
>   specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for
>   usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of
>   an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of
>   browsers as the specification changes.

As a draft feature we need some fallback and a more stable plugin. My recommendation is litera's [jquery-scrollintoview](https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview).

#### Example

```
$('#submit-section').scrollintoview({
    duration: 0
});
```

Comment: hmm...page just jumps like crazy.